# What is the polite way to acknowledge a pregnant lady after a long hiatus?

Tags: conversation, politeness

I knew her well, but I see her again when she's 7-months pregnant. Do I say, "Congrats on the upcoming baby?"

Comment: "Who is the lucky man?"

Comment: Or "You told me you were on the Pill!"

Comment: How long is it since I last saw you? - oh about 7months? - really....

Comment: "We know what causes that, now"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't raise the topic of her pregnancy yourself; my experience of pregnant ladies is that they're very happy to talk about it - in fact, it will probably be the third thing they mention, after "Hello" and whatever current business is at hand - but at the same time (understandably, I think) they tend to resent the fact that the pregnancy is the first thing that anybody notices.  (A friend of mine expressed it this way: "Hey!  I'm right here, behind the belly!)

Don't pretend you haven't noticed that she's pregnant, and - when she mentions it - be friendly and interested.  But treat her like she's your friend, who just happens to be pregnant, rather than as a pregnancy which just happens to have the face of your friend.

In my experience, you can't go wrong with "Hello!  It's been a long time - how have you been?"  If you know her well, tell her she looks great (unless she's obviously just been throwing up.)

Comment: "You look great, even with just a hand."

Answer (score 3):

If she's in her seventh month, then the bump will be hard to miss. I agree that it should not be the first thing to mention:

> Hi! Wow, you're pregnant!

But it's ok to notice it and say so.

> Hi! Long time no see. You look great. I didn't realise you are expecting a baby. When are you due?

Answer (score 1):

If it suits your temperament you can try something flowery, such as: it's so nice to see you in full bloom