# What comes after "octuplet"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

After singletons, twins, triplets, quadruplets, quintuplets, sextuplets, septuplets, and octuplets, what comes next?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96191/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-what-comes-after-octuplet).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We don't often need it, but the word is **nonuplet**.

Next after that comes **decuplets**, who according to the Guinness Book of World Records  were born at Bacacay, Brazil on [April 22, 1946.](http://articles.latimes.com/1987-08-16/news/mn-1940_1_born-dies-woman) (I must admit I'm somewhat sceptical).

It's hard to be dogmatic about the spelling of a word that probably doesn't make it into many (if any) 'authoritative' dictionaries, but I will just say that - Wikipedia notwithstanding - I don't have much time for *decaplets*. [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decuplet,decaplet&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecuplet%3B%2Cc0) an NGram showing that not many others do either (in fact, there are 5 instances of *decaplet* in the NGram corpus, as opposed to 2450 *decuplets*).

Answer (score 2):

[**Nonuplets.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multiple_births)  There doesn't seem to be any record of decuplets, undecuplets, dodecuplets, etc.

Comment: My goodness; they all died!

Comment: In the natural order of things, they generally would.  It's only due to the Miracles of Modern Medicine© that we can have such wonders as OctoMom©.

Answer (score 1):

Next is *nonuplets* followed by *decuplets*. I'm pretty sure there are no recorded *decuplet* births, let alone greater.

**Update:** After further investigation, I came across this image on Wikimedia Commons:

[image: Undecaplets]

> "Pregnancy with 11 fetuses (after Paré)." Giovanni Pico della Mirandola (1463-1494) reported the case of an Italian woman, Dorothea, who allegedly gave birth to undecaplets after having given birth to nonuplets. This illustration is a copy of an original by Ambroise Paré from the 1900 edition of Anomalies and Curiosities of Medicine by George M. Gould and Walter L. Pyle.

Related: The article ["Multiple birth"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_birth) on Wikipedia.

Comment: [Weebles wobble, but they don't fall down...](http://pregnancyandbaby.sheknows.com/pregnancy/baby/How-does-your-center-of-gravity-change-during-pregnancy-277.htm)

Comment: [Related question...](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31542/what-is-the-polite-way-to-acknowledge-a-pregnant-lady-after-a-long-hiatus)