# Single term to include children from multiple births

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

I’m wondering if there is single term to indicate that a child is a twin,  triplet,  quadruplet, etc., without specifying the exact number of siblings in the multiple birth. For example, a “multiple-birth child”.

Answer (score 5):

From various websites like [sjmoms.com](http://www.sjmoms.com/), it looks like the term *multiples* is commonly used for twins, triplets, etc. So I assume one of the multiples could simply be called a *multiple*.

Comment: +1. Wikipedia writes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twins) that the reciprocal single birth is a "singleton"

Comment: +1 And I wrote the same thing [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31675/what-comes-after-octuplet).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've heard it abbreviated to 'multy/multies' too. In context I think that works, but without introducing your subject I think the term multiple would be too general. However, that is probably the best we can do. It's not a subject that arises often in my world, so if it does the context will probably already be clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

"Gemel(s)" (late fourteenth century-) might have worked had it not gone extinct.  The adjective "geminate" would come in handy.  "Geminate brothers" got some hits just now, and "geminate sisters" even more . . .

Comment: Nice answer of historical interest which would benefit from a linked reference to an authoritative source. Welcome to EL&U, enjoy our [tour] and when you have some spare-time, read-up in the [help] about how we work. (You should be aware, your post technically isn't an answer to the question and might have better served as a comment. You  will be able to leave comments on other's posts as soon as you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)).

Comment: When looking up the term "gemel" it seem to be geared towards meaning just "twin".